# Google Maps v3 Javascript: geojson overlays city and country names

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I´m adding some geojson data (polygon features) to a Google Map. Is it possible to add the geojson below the city and country names?

```
map.data.addGeoJson(data);
```

[image]

Comment: No..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The city and country names are on the map tiles.
The GeoJSON data always appears over the map tiles.

You can hide the city and country names on the map tiles using a [Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling),
then overlay your own versions of the city and country names over the GeoJSON layer.