# Show specific countries name on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating project using JavaScript. In my project I have integrated google map.My requirement is i want to show only some specific countries like:

```
India 
USA
Australia
```

Currently I am hiding all countries using:

```
var emptyStyles = 
        [
            {
            featureType: "all",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ]
            }
        ];
        map.setOptions({styles: emptyStyles});
```

I have created plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZQIFZelNROkZcnFZ6mgB?p=preview

Comment: That looks good, so what is your specific problem ? What have you tried to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example where specific cities were displayed on the map. The idea is to

1. hide all the labels(like you already did)
2. create a json array of the place that you want to show labels
   for
3. Iterate through the json array and mark the labels.

You can find the code here: [Display labels only to specific cities in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880908/display-labels-only-to-specific-cities-in-google-maps)

Make following changes to the array:

```
var citiesJSON = {
geonames: [{
  lat: 20.5937,
  lng: 78.9629,
  name: "India"
}, {
  lat: 37.0902,
  lng: -95.7129,
  name: "USA"
}, {
  lat: -25.2744,
  lng: 133.7751,
  name: "Australia"
}]
};
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: I want to show only some countries name on  google map. In the example am not seeing any name

Comment: yes that i understand. The code in this link is for displaying selected cities. instead of cities you can show countries. The only change in the code given on this link would be to change the json array. Store the names and location of all the countries that you want to display in that array. I think it should work

Comment: can you create me plunker for this @Avantika Saini

Comment: I have edited my answer. You literally have all the code now. I am sorry but you have to put in some effort of your own as well

Comment: @ Avantika saini:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed

Comment: @Avantka saini: correct api is https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobox/src/infobox.js

Comment: @ Avantika Thanks for Answer