# Omit Google Maps City/State labels for particular countries Javascript API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Situation: I have a map of Canada using Google Maps Javascript API. The app only involves Canada, so I'd like to hide all the state labels in the US. Basically need to know if there is a way possible with the API to omit all labels but Canada.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the labels by country.  You can hide them all and "manually" add the ones for Canada.  You will need a source for the data {geonames.org is one), and to determine which ones are in view and to display at particular zoom levels.

Similar questions:

- [Google Maps v3 Javascript: geojson overlays city and country names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681818/google-maps-v3-javascript-geojson-overlays-city-and-country-names)
- [Display labels only to specific cities in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880908/display-labels-only-to-specific-cities-in-google-maps)
- [Google maps hide smaller cities (localites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382866/google-maps-hide-smaller-cities-localites)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vk6sh4er/15/)

code snippet:

```js
var mapLabels = [];
var CanadaBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    styles: [{
      "featureType": "administrative.locality",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }]
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': "Canada"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      CanadaBounds = results[0].geometry.viewport;
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    if (south < CanadaBounds.getSouthWest().lat())
      south = CanadaBounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    var west = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    if (west < CanadaBounds.getSouthWest().lng())
      west = CanadaBounds.getSouthWest().lng()
    var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    if (north > 85) north = 85;
    var east = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
    if (east > CanadaBounds.getNorthEast().lng())
      east = CanadaBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
    document.getElementById('bounds').innerHTML = bounds.toUrlValue(6);
    var urlStr = "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?formatted=true&south=" + south.toFixed(6) + "&west=" + west.toFixed(6) + "&north=" + north.toFixed(6) + "&east=" + east.toFixed(6) + "&lang=en&username=geocodezip&style=full";
    $.getJSON(urlStr, function(data) {
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      for (var i = 0; i < data.geonames.length; i++) {
        if (data.geonames[i].countrycode != "CA") continue;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: data.geonames[i].lat,
            lng: data.geonames[i].lng
          },
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 3,
            strokeWeight: 2
          },
          map: map,
          title: data.geonames[i].name
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        var myOptions = {
          content: data.geonames[i].name,
          boxStyle: {
            border: "none",
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: "8pt",
            width: "100px"
          },
          disableAutoPan: true,
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-50, 2),
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.geonames[i].lat, data.geonames[i].lng),
          closeBoxURL: "",
          isHidden: false,
          pane: "mapPane",
          enableEventPropagation: true
        };

        var ibLabel = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        ibLabel.open(map);
        mapLabels.push(ibLabel);
      }
      // map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapLabels.length; i++) {
      if (map.getZoom() > 5) {
        mapLabels[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        mapLabels[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/google-maps-utility-library-v3-infobox@1.1.14/dist/infobox.js"></script>
<div id="bounds"></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```